# how to use c++ to get full path with %systemroot% or other?

Tags: c++, windows

some time i get a path, system will take me that

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE
```

i need to get the really full path.

how can i do it by c++?

i'd try SHGetSpecialFolderLocation, but i cannot accept string param.
and google cannot find other Win API to do it.

do not tell me that use SHGetSpecialFolderLocation, it cannot work.
because u must get a map that from string(like %SystemRoot%) to HWND(linke CSIDL_PERSONAL) but MS do not give this map!